# Querying the Oracle SCOTT Schema – What salary is the closest to the average?

Tags: sql, oracle, average

Using the [SCOTT Schema](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SCOTT). I’m trying to get the person who has a salary closest to the average.

```
SELECT sal
      FROM (  SELECT sal
                FROM emp
            ORDER BY ABS ( (SELECT AVG (SAL) FROM EMP) - sal))
     WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Can the solution above be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a non-standard Oracle feature. Data in subqueries doesn't have an order originally, but in Oracle you can order it, so as to be able to apply the ROWNUM criteria later. ROWNUM is also Oracle specific.

Moreover there can be several employees with the same salary, where you are picking one of them arbitrarily rather than showing them all.

Here is how to select the employee(s) with the salary closest to the avarage in standard SQL:

```
select *
from emp
order by abs(sal - avg(sal) over())
fetch first row with ties;
```

This last line is available only as of Oracle 12c.

In older versions (that is Oracle 9i, 10i or 11g) you'd rank your rows instead:

```
select empno, ename, sal
from
(
  select empno, ename, sal, rank() over (order by diff) as rnk
  from
  (
    select emp.*, abs(sal - avg(sal) over()) as diff
    from emp
  ) evaluated
) ranked
where rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Hi, with my 12c database, your row limiting clause throws an error.  When I change your clause to `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES`, it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
with av as (select avg(sal) avgsal from scott.emp)
select emp.*, abs(emp.sal-av.avgsal) dist 
  from scott.emp, av 
  order by dist;
```

Above looks better for me but probably you can get it best with analytic function. Something like:

```
select * from (
  select emp.*, abs(avg(emp.sal) over () - sal) diff 
    from scott.emp order by diff) 
where rownum = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Pulling employee data back with the subquery:

```
select empno, sal, SalDif
from 
  (
    select empno, sal, abs(sal - (select avg(sal) from emp)) as SalDif
    from emp
    order by SalDif
  )
where rownum = 1;
```

or as a CTE:

```
with CTE as
  (
    select empno, sal, abs(sal - (select avg(sal) from emp)) as SalDif
    from emp
    order by SalDif
  )
select empno, sal, SalDif
from CTE
where rownum = 1;
```